# Importing and transforming nested XML into Microsoft Access

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt

I have a huge file; bigger than I can load into Excel and I would like to get it into Access to do some operations on it (find every entry with a certain field, within a spectrum of dates, etc), but just straight up loading the file into Access gives me about 7 different tables with no key or ID to link them together.

Looking online it seems I have to do a transformation using XLST as I import the file, but I am already way out of my depth with this.

So, when I just straight up open a similar (but a bit smaller) file with Excel, I get a flat structure like I want. So how come I can't use whatever Excel uses to determine the structure in Access? Can I export whatever it used to get my data straight?

Here's a snippet of a single entry:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rap rereport="true">
  <name>Gramex</name>
  <report-date>2017-08-14T08:29:43+02:00</report-date>
  <period>
    <from>2017-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</from>
    <to>2017-07-01T00:00:00+02:00</to>
  </period>
  <publications>
    <publication id="LFwlaU97RbCQZzsn5NWGwQ" type="NORMAL" runtype="RERUN" night="false" archive="false">
      <channel>RØ4</channel>
      <distribution-channels />
      <production production-number="14901715527" dr-production="false">
        <parent-production>
          <production production-number="14901615000" dr-production="false">
            <title>Regionale nyheder</title>
            <year />
            <country />
            <content />
            <department-code>490</department-code>
            <category>Nyheder</category>
            <producer />
          </production>
        </parent-production>
        <title>Regionale nyheder</title>
        <year />
        <country />
        <content />
        <department-code>490</department-code>
        <category>Nyheder</category>
        <producer />
      </production>
      <start>2017-01-01T10:30:00+01:00</start>
      <end>2017-01-01T10:32:00+01:00</end>
      <duration>PT2M0.000S</duration>
      <first-time-published>2017-01-01T10:30:00+01:00</first-time-published>
      <title>Regionale nyheder</title>
      <alternative-title>Regionale nyheder</alternative-title>
      <briks complete="VERIFIED" not-verified="0">
        <brik id="XjGj5q1HTCuHIZh1O29Gcg" duration="00:17" offset="00:00">
          <genre id="2">JINGLE</genre>
          <musa content-id="qDzwjqlUTR2VK6Avwg0gPQ" dr-production="true">
            <media-code>5</media-code>
            <album type="DR intern">
              <title>P4 Lyddesign</title>
              <label>DR</label>
              <catalog-number>null</catalog-number>
              <musa-number complete="true">6700089</musa-number>
              <track duration="10:00" live="false">
                <side>1</side>
                <cut>1</cut>
                <partcut />
                <title>P4 Lyddesign 2016</title>
                <work-title />
                <record-country id="7">Danmark</record-country>
                <associated-country />
                <isrc />
                <record-year>2016</record-year>
                <catalog-number />
              </track>
            </album>
            <persons>
              <person role-source-system="MUSA" role-code="1" role="Komponist">Bjarke Rasmussen</person>
              <person role-source-system="MUSA" role-code="4" role="Hovedkunstner">Bjarke Rasmussen</person>
            </persons>
          </musa>
        </brik>
        <brik id="u2Qh2ozMRuilWa_XofW5Ug" duration="00:08" offset="01:24">
          <genre id="2">JINGLE</genre>
          <musa content-id="3f6e4oShQxWwTDNoLE_4xw" dr-production="true">
            <media-code>5</media-code>
            <album type="DR intern">
              <title>P4 kendinge (2015)</title>
              <label>DR</label>
              <catalog-number>null</catalog-number>
              <musa-number complete="false">6700073</musa-number>
              <track duration="00:07" live="false">
                <side>1</side>
                <cut>28</cut>
                <partcut />
                <title>Nyh/Gen/Break 1</title>
                <work-title />
                <record-country id="7">Danmark</record-country>
                <associated-country />
                <isrc />
                <record-year>2015</record-year>
                <catalog-number />
              </track>
            </album>
            <persons>
              <person role-source-system="MUSA" role-code="1" role="Komponist">Bjarke Rasmussen</person>
              <person role-source-system="MUSA" role-code="4" role="Hovedkunstner">Bjarke Rasmussen</person>
            </persons>
          </musa>
        </brik>
        <brik id="5YkkrUSsQuCESShI_WJw2g" duration="00:09" offset="01:51">
          <genre id="2">JINGLE</genre>
          <musa content-id="vEUgsCypQPi_AwEKbrrbdg" dr-production="true">
            <media-code>5</media-code>
            <album type="DR intern">
              <title>P4 kendinge (2015)</title>
              <label>DR</label>
              <catalog-number>null</catalog-number>
              <musa-number complete="false">6700073</musa-number>
              <track duration="02:08" live="false">
                <side>1</side>
                <cut>25</cut>
                <partcut />
                <title>Nyh/Gen/Vejr Bed</title>
                <work-title />
                <record-country id="7">Danmark</record-country>
                <associated-country />
                <isrc />
                <record-year>2015</record-year>
                <catalog-number />
              </track>
            </album>
            <persons>
              <person role-source-system="MUSA" role-code="1" role="Komponist">Bjarke Rasmussen</person>
              <person role-source-system="MUSA" role-code="4" role="Hovedkunstner">Bjarke Rasmussen</person>
            </persons>
          </musa>
        </brik>
        <brik id="kTzt3NyfQL6ohT7KXLWpxg" duration="00:08" offset="00:37">
          <genre id="2">JINGLE</genre>
          <musa content-id="3f6e4oShQxWwTDNoLE_4xw" dr-production="true">
            <media-code>5</media-code>
            <album type="DR intern">
              <title>P4 kendinge (2015)</title>
              <label>DR</label>
              <catalog-number>null</catalog-number>
              <musa-number complete="false">6700073</musa-number>
              <track duration="00:07" live="false">
                <side>1</side>
                <cut>28</cut>
                <partcut />
                <title>Nyh/Gen/Break 1</title>
                <work-title />
                <record-country id="7">Danmark</record-country>
                <associated-country />
                <isrc />
                <record-year>2015</record-year>
                <catalog-number />
              </track>
            </album>
            <persons>
              <person role-source-system="MUSA" role-code="1" role="Komponist">Bjarke Rasmussen</person>
              <person role-source-system="MUSA" role-code="4" role="Hovedkunstner">Bjarke Rasmussen</person>
            </persons>
          </musa>
        </brik>
      </briks>
    </publication>
  </publications>
</rap>
```

Comment: You could try opening the file in something like [XML Notepad](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7973) and delete any repeating sections to cut down on the size while keeping the structure. A meaningful sample of the input will be necessary to get any kind of useful response. A couple of screenshots are not much to go on, really.

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestion, I'll add it to the top post,

Comment: I edited it with a pastebin, but for some reason the edit didn't go through.

Comment: And what is your desired result? What data in this XML are you trying to extract?

Comment: You might consider using XPath, and leaving your data in XML.  You can do all the things your considering with XPath (extract values, find values within date ranges, etc).